# Instrumental Variable : the sense of "Local" in the LATE

Tags: instrumental-variables

What intuitive sense can be given to the word "Local" in the LATE?

"Local" compared to what ?

Comment: Intuition: running a randomized controlled trial with stage IV cancer patients won't estimate the treatment effect on stage 1 tumors. If you have an instrument for treatment, you're only estimating the treatment effect for the subset of your population where the instrument generates exogenous variation. @Andreas's answer gives a great, more formal definition.

Comment: What does LATE stand for?

Answer (score 4):

The LATE framework assumes that there is a continuum of types, say $U \sim [0, 1]$, that may all react differently to the treatment.

Only a subset of all types reacts to the instrument by changing their treatment status. Under the monotonicity assumption this will always be an interval, say $[a, b]$ with $0 < a <b < 1$.

The LATE gives you the average treatment effect averaged over types $[a, b]$, whereas the ATE will give you the average treatment effect averaged over all types $[0, 1]$.

The LATE is "local" in the sense that it looks only at the treatment effects in the neighborhood of the types that are affected by the instrument.

Comment: Anyone can give me a list of most popular case of studies (papers) where the instrumental variable is used in impact evaluation in economics please ? i know a few but i'll need some more. Thanks !